# Joining aggregated data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, aggregate-functions

```
select CategoryId, SUM(DVDPrice) 
from Films 
group by CategoryId;
```

[image]

```
select CategoryId, COUNT(MemberId) 
from FavCategory 
group by CategoryId;
```

[image]

What I want is to display the data in one table. Tried to join the results on CategoryId field:

```
select FavCategory.CategoryId, 
       COUNT(MemberId), 
       SUM(DVDPrice) from FavCategory 
inner join Films on FavCategory.CategoryId = Films.CategoryId 
group by FavCategory.CategoryId;
```

[image]

Results looks quite odd, they are somehow multiplied. I found a solution - used a subquery in the outer select, but my question is why the join solution did not work. I will be appreciated if anybody could sort it out.

regards

Comment: `SELECT * FROM FavCategory JOIN Films USING (CategoryId)` to observe the effect of your join, then consider what happens when you aggregate.

Comment: The COUNT values is correct, that is it shows nr of records in Films table with categoryid = 1 multiplied by nr of records in FavCategory table. I thought aggregated data is retrieved from both tables and than joined, but it's rather retrieved first, than joined and finally aggregated.

Comment: Is the first table ok? then name of the rows do not correspond with the query.

Comment: The reason the results get multiplied is that your join will give you every combination of the 2 tables. So if for category 1 there were 3 records on each table then you will get 9 combinations on the join, hence a single row on one of the tables is counted multiple times

Comment: @Łukasz, your assumption is right: tables are joined first, then the resultset of the join is aggregated.

Comment: Note that for the count, if you landed up with a single member id being counted multiple times due to the join you can use a COUNT(DISTINCT MemeberId) to eliminate those duplicates from the counts.